# c# calling base() with calculated result from parameters

Tags: c#, constructor

I need to write an Exception class that the message is determined automatically according to the input parameters. How can I pass that dynamic message to the base()?

Here is the codes of what I want to do but it's not working

```
public class MyException : Exception
{

    public MyException(int ErrCode, Dictionary<string, string> Params) : base(msg_external)
    {
        ErrorDetail = ErrorList[ErrCode];

        string msg_internal = "";
        string msg_external = "";

        foreach (var item in Params)
        {
            msg_internal = ErrorDetail.MessageInternal.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
            msg_external = ErrorDetail.MessageExternal.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        //now I need to pass msg_external to the base(). how?

    }

}
```

This question is not about calling constructor after my constructor, it is about passing a different value to the parent constructor.

Comment: You aren't showing what the `base` class is. Is `MyException` a method inside a class that implements `Exception`?

Comment: if you _call pass msg_external to the base()_ you are again generate new instance of the base class, no problem with that?

Comment: Move that logic into a static method. Pass the params into the method and the result of the method call into `base`.

Comment: @RufusL Yes you are wright. I've just added the class definition. MyException extends Exception.

Comment: @Will I can only generate a static method without any parameters. Once I add a parameter to that static method, it shows another error "cannot convert method group to string"

Comment: @combo_ci no that's not what I want. I want the object be created only once and initialized by the calculated message.

Comment: ok, then you can put 2 constracotr in your base class, with that first one have no parameter and second one have parameter `msg_external`....if you want i could explain more in answer with code sample

Comment: @combo_ci It's a different question. My question is not about the sequence of the constructor calling but passing a different variable.

Comment: *cannot convert method group to string* I'd suggest buying CLR Via C# and reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's code that'll do what you want.

Assumes good input. Error checking recommended.

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    private static string BaseExceptionMessage(int ErrCode, Dictionary<string,string> Params)
    {
        return Params.Aggregate(ErrorList[ErrCode].MessageExternal, (i, a) => i.Replace(a.Key, a.Value));
    }
    public MyException(int ErrCode, Dictionary<string, string> Params) : base(BaseExceptionMessage(ErrCode, Params))
    {
        ErrorDetail = ErrorList[ErrCode];

        string msg_internal = "";
        string msg_external = "";

        foreach (var item in Params)
        {
            msg_internal = ErrorDetail.MessageInternal.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
            msg_external = ErrorDetail.MessageExternal.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: But in question in line _now I need to pass msg_external to the base(). how?_ he want to send _msg_external _ after foreach...is your code do that?or call base in initial of MyException ?

Comment: my solution does the equivalent of the foreach prior to passing it to base. also, assumes that ErrorList is static.

Comment: This solution works. I need to pass a calculated variable to the base(), sequence isn't a matter.